# UIButton always moves back to its first location?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am having this hair pulling problem, i hope anybody will be able to help me out. it seems like a little thing but i have not been able to find any solution.

I have a UIButton that i want to move around with a animation block. Everytime i click the button i have it move to a new location, the button always moves to the correct location the problem is that it always moves from its first location to its new location.

lets say that i have a button at `(0,0)` i then move it to `(0,50)` works like a beaut!
Now i want to move the button to `(0,100)` and i expect it to animate from `(0,50)` to `(0,100)` but what it does it animate from `(0,0)` to `(0,100)` so it ends up in the right location, but moves FROM the wrong location.

i move the `UIButton` by setting a a new frame in a animation block

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f
                              delay:0.0f
                            options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear
                         animations:^{
                         }
                         completion:nil];
```

in my case i move the button in a completion block when other controls a finished moving.

i really hope somebody out there knows exatly what im talking about and have the answer for me.

the code i use for animating the uibutton is this, the buttons name is "btnAddPhoneNumber" and its also the "sender"

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear
                 animations:^{
                     txtNewPhoneNumber.frame = CGRectMake(newXnumber, newYnumber, txtPhoneNumber.frame.size.width, txtPhoneNumber.frame.size.height);

                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     txtNewPhoneNumber.placeholder = @"here you go!";

                     //animate add textfield button.
                     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f
                                           delay:0
                                         options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear
                                      animations:^{



                                          [sender setFrame:CGRectMake(btnAddPhoneNumber.frame.origin.x, newYnumber, btnAddPhoneNumber.frame.size.width, btnAddPhoneNumber.frame.size.height)];

                                          txtNewPhoneNumberTitle.frame = CGRectMake(newXtitle, newYtitle, txtPhoneNumberTitle.frame.size.width, txtPhoneNumberTitle.frame.size.height);

                                          [btnDelete setFrame:btnDeleteRect];
                                      }
                                      completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                      }];
                 }];
```

thank you for reading my question, and for helping me find a solution.

EDIT (added code example)

Comment: Can you please post the code which you have written for both?

Comment: Hi ACB, i have added the complete animation block.

Comment: In the completion block can you print the frame of txtNewPhoneNumber in console and check if it has updated the frame properly when it is in completion block?

Comment: If Tobi's answer is not working, there is one dirty work around as [self performSelector:@selector(callSecondAnimation)withObject:nil afterDelay:1.5.0f)]; inside your completion block. But that is not recommended.

Comment: Hi ACB The frame of the button seems to update correctly
{{270, 38}, {30, 30}}
{{270, 76}, {30, 30}}

but when i click it it still animates from  {{270, 0}, {30, 30}}

Comment: How about the work around I suggested, was that working? You can use that as the last option.

Comment: i dont think i understand how you want me to "callSecondAnimation" ?

Comment: I have added as answer, since I cant post it here. Two options are added, try with second one first.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState` to the options of the second animation, see if it solves your problem.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f
                              delay:0.0f
                            options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                         animations:^{
                         }
                         completion:nil];
```

Another way to go would be to set the frame of the button again (to the same value) in the completion handler of the second animation.

Comment: Hi Tobi. i have tried both and it do not make any different it still animates from its original frame.

Comment: Could you please provide all the related code? including the action for the button and the part where you set the values for `newYnumber`

Answer (score 0):

Check this work around. As I mentioned in comments, you can use this as your last option. Not a recommended approach.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear
                 animations:^{
                     txtNewPhoneNumber.frame = CGRectMake(newXnumber, newYnumber, txtPhoneNumber.frame.size.width, txtPhoneNumber.frame.size.height);

                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     txtNewPhoneNumber.placeholder = @"here you go!";

                     [self performSelector:@selector(callSecondAnimation) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.5f)]; //or 0.5f
                 }];

- (void)callSecondAnimation {
    //animate add textfield button.
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear
                     animations:^{

                         [sender setFrame:CGRectMake(btnAddPhoneNumber.frame.origin.x, newYnumber, btnAddPhoneNumber.frame.size.width, btnAddPhoneNumber.frame.size.height)];

                         txtNewPhoneNumberTitle.frame = CGRectMake(newXtitle, newYtitle, txtPhoneNumberTitle.frame.size.width, txtPhoneNumberTitle.frame.size.height);

                         [btnDelete setFrame:btnDeleteRect];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     }];
}
```

**Update:**

Try this first,

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear
                 animations:^{
                     txtNewPhoneNumber.frame = CGRectMake(newXnumber, newYnumber, txtPhoneNumber.frame.size.width, txtPhoneNumber.frame.size.height);

                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     txtNewPhoneNumber.placeholder = @"here you go!";
                     txtNewPhoneNumber.frame = CGRectMake(newXnumber, newYnumber, txtPhoneNumber.frame.size.width, txtPhoneNumber.frame.size.height);//try setting it here once and then call next one
                     [self callSecondAnimation];
                 }];

- (void)callSecondAnimation {
    //animate add textfield button.
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear
                     animations:^{

                         [sender setFrame:CGRectMake(btnAddPhoneNumber.frame.origin.x, newYnumber, btnAddPhoneNumber.frame.size.width, btnAddPhoneNumber.frame.size.height)];

                         txtNewPhoneNumberTitle.frame = CGRectMake(newXtitle, newYtitle, txtPhoneNumberTitle.frame.size.width, txtPhoneNumberTitle.frame.size.height);

                         [btnDelete setFrame:btnDeleteRect];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     }];
}
```

Comment: None of the two suggestions make any difference. Do you know what is causing the problem since you are suggesting these approaches ? thank you for taking the time to help, really appreciate it!

Comment: my guess was that, completion block was getting called before the previous animation finishes. So the plan was to introduce a delay in between these two animations in such a way that user will feel like it is continuous. So if you just remove the second animation, is the first animation working properly to move to the desired point?

Comment: I see what you mean, but sadly that does not seem to solve my problem. Im finding this very weird!

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, the view used AutoLayout, when i removed the tick in AutoLayout the new position of my button is saved, and the next animation continues from the previously location.

thanks to ACB and Tobi for their input their helped me try different solutions that ended up fixing the problem!